# Replicating a Redshift table in AWS Aurora RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a use case where Redshift is being used as a data lake where raw data from multiple tables from various databases owned by different services are dumped. There are certain tools that run queries on the raw service tables in Redshift at regular intervals and build aggregated tables in Redshift.

How can I get these aggregated tables in Redshift into AWS Aurora MySQL in a way that the table in MySQL is an exact replica of the table in Redshift?
A few points to note:

(1) This Redshift -> MySQL sync needs to happen multiple times in a day and

(2) There should be no downtime on the MySQL instance.

PS: I've previously tried to use `UNLOAD` on Redshift to dump the table contents as CSV and then upload these CSVs into MySQL using `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` , but this method does not handle deletion of entries in MySQL; That is, when a row is not present in the Redshift table, it will not get removed from the table in MySQL.

Comment: Perhaps you can utilise AWS Data Pipeline for this. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-redshiftrdsincremental.html for the opposite direction which should be easily adaptable.

Comment: @MP24  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the data pipeline approach this still boils down to loading CSVs into MySQL which doesn't handle deletes.